# Security Concern in Cordova/Phonegapp Application

Tags: cordova, webview, hybrid-mobile-app

My team will develop an Employee Portal to manage all Human Resource related requirements. It will be developed using Cordova/Phonegap.

Because we use WebView in Cordova, then all resource files: HTML, JS, CSS, will be included by default in APK files. All users can view these resource files, which can be a HTML form and all logic inside JS files.

When all users (even without login) can view all HTML and JS files, is it bad idea or something to not worry about? Because in my mind, they can exploit all the form because they know the Endpoint URL and all POST fields inside the HTML form.

It is no problem if they can view Form and Fields after login (in web-based app it usually happens), but the concern is for other people which has not been logged in, they are able to do this.

In server-side, sure we have extra-validation to prevent attacker, but when all users know about Endpoint and all POST fields, they have one step closer to hack, right?

Once again, is it bad idea or something to not worry about? and how to secure the resources file? For now I have no idea.

Comment: `JWT` will add some security on access of APIs.

Comment: thank you @HardikVaghani, i will explore `jwt`, but how about security concern about user that can view all form and fields without login?

Comment: Session management. You will be able to achieve with localstorage or sessionstorage.

Comment: @HardikVaghani sure, it will be done by default

Comment: Then i  think its enough secure so that guest users will not be able to go through.

Comment: thank you @HardikVaghani for your opinion, i agree with that aspect. Now how about if non-logged-in user do reverse-engineering then copy/imitate the form because they have full source code?

Comment: For that purpose i suggested token based security __OR__ you can use oauth or something like that.

Comment: okay thank you, noted...

Comment: Go through this once : https://www.checkmarx.com/2015/10/23/the-worst-phonegap-security-issues-and-how-to-avoid-them/

Comment: thank you, the topic in that article is something i am looking for

Answer (score 1):

Go through this article once [The Worst PhoneGap Security Issues And How To Avoid Them](https://www.checkmarx.com/2015/10/23/the-worst-phonegap-security-issues-and-how-to-avoid-them/)

It has issues listed with solution to overcome for

1. Cross-Site Scripting
2. Lack of Source Code Protection
3. JavaScript Security Issues
4. Excessive permission granting

Regards.

Comment: These are also good references: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/security/index.html, https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/privacy/index.html